# Netflix Issue : Firefox can't find the server at movies.netflix.com

Tags: netflix

I'm new to Ubuntu world...recently, I have installed Netflix desktop on my system. But, it is not working...giving an error "Firefox can't find the server at movies.netflix.com."..

I have Firefox and Chrome web browser installed on my system. Netflix website is opening on Chrome but not on firefox.

Please help me. Thank You

Comment: What exact commands did you use to install netflix-desktop and how are you starting the app?

Comment: Don't remember the commands....I googled it and followed the steps......I added netflix desktop in left side toolbar and accessing it.....

Comment: full error msg :

Comment: Server not found
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          Firefox can't find the server at movies.netflix.com.
        

        
        

  Check the address for typing errors such as
    ww.example.com instead of
    www.example.com
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Answer (score -1):

I've been having the same issue for quite a while, and just recently fixed it. I was getting the exact same error, but it would actually work on the rare occasion when I closed and re-opened it a ton of times. I changed the default DNS servers for my connection in Ubuntu to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 (Google DNS), and it's worked 100% so far.

I'm still not sure exactly what caused this though. I'm using Xubuntu 64 bit, I didn't have wine installed previous to netflix-desktop, and am using Mediacom internet.